# Mismatching versions of `parity-scale-codec` were found!

Tags: ink, smart-contract

## Problem

When executing the following command, an error occurred.

```
cargo contract build
ERROR: Mismatching versions of `parity-scale-codec` were found!
Please ensure that your contract and your ink! dependencies use a compatible version of this package.
```

## Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 wsl
- cargo-contract: 2.0.0-alpha.3-unknown-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
- ink:

  ```
  ink = { version = "4.0.0-alpha.3", default-features = false }
  scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
  scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
  ```
- rustc: 1.66.0-nightly

## Code

The template code

```
cargo contract new alpha403
```

I have checked the version of `parity-scale-codec`, it is version `3` in both my ink! project and in the ink package of version `4.0.0-alpha.3`.

Comment: I have same `Environment` as yours except `OS: macOS Monterey` and I haven't faced issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a `nightly` compiler to build your contract. With the recent alphas it is now possible to build contracts using the `stable` toolchain.

If you run `cargo +stable contract build` everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

check out cargo tree, than just:

```shell
$ cargo tree | grep scale-codec
```

To find out if you have multiple dependencies with different versions in the repo